# Magento undefined jquery

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, javascript, jquery, prototype-js

I've added jquery 1.8.2 to both my page.xml file and the corresponding directory.. however i am still getting multiple Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined errors.

Jquery no conflict has been added.

In the page.xml file the script src is

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery-1.8.2.min.js</script></action>
```

and it is the first script.

```
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

<action method="addJs"><script>jquery-1.8.2.min.js</script></action>

        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>

        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>

        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
```

ect.

Comment: Looks like you're loading in Jquery twice (ajaxcart is loading it too) - one could be un-registering the other, despite them being the same versions.

Comment: @DouglasRadburn i've disable and reenabled it with no luck

Comment: Have you tried calling noConflict as soon as jQuery is loaded?  The call is further down the page (and after a jQuery block of code!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new .js file for eg. `no-conflict.js` and add the following content on it:

`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

And include your `no-conflict.js` just after your

`<action method="addJs"><script>jquery-1.8.2.min.js</script></action>` like this:

`<action method="addJs"><script>no-conflict.js</script></action>`

Then write your jQuery like this:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
// write your code here
});
```

P.S. for more information on solving jquery conflict refer http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-solve-jquery-and-prototype.html

Comment: I have tried this. If i add `$j(document).ready(function(){
// write your code here
});` then i get $j is undefined

Comment: just check in the page view source no-conflict.js is loading after the jquerylibeary

Comment: it is @pradeepsanku. The file containing `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` is next after jquery. The nocoflict.js gets `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ` as well

Comment: which magento version you are using ?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 @pradeepsanku

Comment: $j(document).ready(function(){ // write your code here }); under this function what did you written can you share.

Comment: I encased my jquery-1.8.2.min.js in the function. I get 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $j is not defined @pradeepsanku

Comment: $j(document).ready(function(){
 $j('.button').click(function(){
});
});

you have to use something like this

Comment: just check in page view source of  the page your noconfict.js is loaded first then jquery1-8 is loaded.it should be reverse.

Comment: i have fixed that, however i am still getting the errors.

Comment: solved for you.what was the issue ?

Comment: i made two separate jquery 1.8.2 files one was altered slightly for an extension